# Adding an object to a list in c# .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add an object to a List but whenever I go to check what's inside the List I get "SomeNamespace.SomeClass". I'm importing an Excel table into a 2D array and I'm passing its values to an object which I'm trying to add to a List. Here's the code (I'm excluding the part where I import the Excel file because I successfully retrieve everything I need, I just can't add it to a List):

```
            int rowNumber= xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int columnNumber= xlRange.Columns.Count;
            object[,] valueArray;

            List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();

            valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

            for (int i = 2; i <= rowNumber; i++)
            {
                SomeClass objRequest = new SomeClass();

                objRequest.Field1 = valueArray[i, 1].ToString();
                objRequest.Field2 = valueArray[i, 2].ToString();
                objRequest.Field3 = valueArray[i, 3].ToString();
                objRequest.Field4 = valueArray[i, 4].ToString();
                objRequest.Field5 = valueArray[i, 5].ToString();
                objRequest.Field6 = valueArray[i, 6].ToString();
                objRequest.Field7 = valueArray[i, 7].ToString();
                list.Add(objRequest);
            }

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            }
```

I'm currently using VS 2010 if it can help.

Comment: * whenever I go to check what's inside the List I get "SomeNamespace.SomeClass"* is it in MessageBox? If you are seeing this string in message box then this is due to `.ToString()`(Which is not overridden). If you want to check specific field in message box then What is it? What is `type` of that field

Comment: Did you override `SomeClass.ToString`?

Comment: Have you overriden the `ToString()` function in `SomeClass`? If not you're using the default implementation, which gives `Namespace.ClassName`.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#Overriding for more information on the `.ToString()`-Method and how to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have 7 field in `objRequest` and then you want to `toString()` it?
You can either `toString()` all 7 of them 1 by 1 or make a method to display all of them.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= rowNumber; i++)
{
    SomeClass objRequest = new SomeClass();

    objRequest.Field1 = valueArray[i, 1].ToString();
    objRequest.Field2 = valueArray[i, 2].ToString();
    objRequest.Field3 = valueArray[i, 3].ToString();
    objRequest.Field4 = valueArray[i, 4].ToString();
    objRequest.Field5 = valueArray[i, 5].ToString();
    objRequest.Field6 = valueArray[i, 6].ToString();
    objRequest.Field7 = valueArray[i, 7].ToString();
    list.Add(objRequest);
}

foreach (var item in list)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
}
```

#### Method 1: toString() All of them

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Field 1: " + item.Field1.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 2: " + item.Field2.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 3: " + item.Field3.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 4: " + item.Field4.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 5: " + item.Field5.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 6: " + item.Field6.ToString() + "\n" +
            "Field 7: " + item.Field7.ToString()
    );
}
```

#### Method 2: Make a method to display all of them

```
public static string toStringAll()
{
    return "Field 1: " + Field1.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 2: " + Field2.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 3: " + Field3.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 4: " + Field4.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 5: " + Field5.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 6: " + Field6.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 7: " + Field7.ToString();
}
```

#### Method 3: Override toString() in SomeClass

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Field 1: " + Field1.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 2: " + Field2.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 3: " + Field3.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 4: " + Field4.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 5: " + Field5.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 6: " + Field6.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Field 7: " + Field7.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Most complete answer, thank you, worked. I'm new to c# and .NET

Answer (score 3):

Thats because SomeClass doesnt override the ToString-method.

Try to override it inside SomeClass with the following method...

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{Field1}, {Field2}"; //etc etc
}
```